# Importing Remote Components/Methods in Webpack Module Federation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, webpack-module-federation

We are using react webpack module federation for a POC projec and we are facing this  error when using tsx file(instead of js file used in this examples provide by module federation team)

**Cannot find module 'lib/Typography' or its corresponding type declarations.**

We have used typings (.d.ts) file and included its path in tsconfig.json without any success.

Right now we are able to circumvent it by using  `// @ts-ignore`  which might not be the best solution in the longer run.

Any help/leads on this will be great for us.

```
import Typography from 'lib/Typography';
// @ts-ignore
const RecentPaymentLazy = lazy(() => import('payment/RecentPayments'));
```

typings file (lib.d.ts)

```
/// <reference types="react" />
import { ButtonProps, CircularProgressProps, IconButtonProps, TextFieldProps, TypographyProps } from "@mui/material";
declare module "lib/Typography" {
  const Typography: React.ComponentType<TypographyProps>;
  export default Typography;
}
```

tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false
  },
  "lib": [
    "es2018",
    "dom"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../core/src/lib.d.ts"
  ],
}
```

Webpack file

```
 new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'core',
      remotes: {
        payment: 'payment@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js',
        lib:'lib@http://localhost:3008/remoteEntry.js',
      },
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  Running into this now

Comment: @PatrickDench- i am afraid no. i resorted to using Javascript for now in webpack module federation

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a poly-repo solution, I've put together this sample app with some instructions to share the type definitions of exposed files: https://github.com/jrandeniya/federated-types-sample

It's relatively straight forward using the great work done by [@touk/federated-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@touk/federated-types)  and [webpack-remote-types-plugin](https://github.com/ruanyl/webpack-remote-types-plugin)